# Binding a winforms grid to subsonic classes .Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to bind a winforms grid to a subsonic DB Generated class. I come from a ASP.Net background where this works perfectly but when i try to do this using Win Forms it never loads the data and does not allow me to edit or update.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found through trial and error that the best way to do this is to load the data via code in the form load event or any other such event before the data is required.

Also once the collection is loaded it should be bound to the data source property of the datasource you are using.